# Sensor for detect there is a car or not ?

Tags: sensors

please I'm aiming to do a project for parking system but first of thing I need a sensor to detect there is a car or not other than ultrasonic sensor ..

please any one know any kind of those sensors ? pressure sensor or normal sensor ?

Comment: Use an inductive loop, like they use in front of traffic lights. Photo-reflector would be another option. Could you expand on your requirements? Is it placed outside? Could you mount a sensor on a ceiling (to prevent dirt from interfering)? Can it be placed in front of the car?  Why can't you use a ultrasonic sensor?

Comment: When I Googled `car detection sensor -ultrasonic` I got 8.4 million hits. Are you looking for something other than what that search found?

Answer (score 2):

Ideas and concepts you could use:

1 - Laser tripwire - acts like a laser security system. If the beam is broken, then you car is there. Put a laser on one side of your garage and a photocell and the other and read its value.

2 - photocell under the car - if the area is always lit, you might be able to put a photocell below the parking spot. Then when your car is on the photocell, it return a different value then when there is nothing.

3 - pressure/weight sensor - both will detect the presence of a heavy object on them.

Hope those ideas hepled you!

Comment: thank you for your answer but please can you explain to me the second one (photocell under the car) I did not understand :)

Comment: a photocell is a variable resistor, it calculates the intensity off light. If you were in a lit area, lets say the sensor reads 500. then when the car is on the sensor, it will drop to something like 70.

Comment: can you give me a link for pressure/weight sensor or picture please :)

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1893

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/products/166