# Arduino project list: What do I need?

Tags: arduino-uno

Being new to Arduino I would like to know if I can build a project on this platform.

I want to connect Arduino to a few car parking sensors, a video camera and a mobile phone. The preferred language is JavaScript.

- Is it something feasible?
- Are there JavaScript libraries that can help with automation?
- What version of Arduino should I use? Arduino UNO or something else?

Thanks,
George

Comment: Can't be answered: you don't give enough detail about what you want to do. However, the word "camera" when coupled with "Arduino" usually means "No. Get a Pi."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Arduino is in C/C++/a bit of Java Script. That's the normal IDE language so no you can't change it. Even other compiler mostly use one of the many C languages.

Car parking sensor question anwsered [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29997/sensor-for-detect-there-is-a-car-or-not/29998#29998).

For the hardware, use an UNO Rev3. It's the latest and most expandable board. It's also cheaper then others and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I have also found out about this JS library for Arduino and more:

http://johnny-five.io/